# NodeJS with Docker-compose

Tags: node.js, docker

I try to run node js in docker. I found error when run command docker-compose up. This is the folder hierarchy:

```
test_dock4
- db
- web
  - node_modules
  - Dockerfile
  - index.js
  - package-lock.json
  - package.json
- docker-compose.yml
```

---

Here is my docker-compose.yml code

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    container_name: web
    build: ./web/
    links:
      - db
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://user:pass@db:5432/new_databases
    command: node index.js
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./web:/webapp
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
      - POSTGRES_DATABASE=new_databases
```

---

Here is my Dockerfile code

```
FROM node:8.12.0
# Create app directory
RUN mkdir /webapp
WORKDIR /webapp

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /webapp
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /webapp

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

---

Error:

```
web    |     Error: Cannot find module '/webapp/index.js'
web    |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
web    |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
web    |     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
web    |     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
web    |     at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
web exited with code 1
```

What goes wrong? I am new to Docker. But I've try several things, such as clear all container, try to reproduce it, but it seems nothing works.
Any help, it'll be very helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replicated the same scenario and the problem is with the volume you have mounted through your docker-compose.yml. You have already copied all the files required to the webapp folder through Dockerfile and trying to mount the same folder outside which is trying to override the files and makes the webapp folder empty.

```
volumes:
  - ./web:/webapp
```

Remove the above two lines from docker-compose.yml and try it

Tested.

Comment: brilliant, it works. Thanks! anw, then come new error :v. If you dont mind, please help me. I'll post it in another questions.

Answer (score 0):

When docker container starts, it is trying to run the command:  `command: node index.js`.  It cannot find the file and it fails.     You need to check the fils correctly copied in the /webapp folder

Comment: How to check if the file already copied into /webapp? And if I did not found the file on that folder, what should I do to make it copied? I thought this code "# Bundle app source COPY . /webapp" in Dockerfile are the one who will do the job (copying all, including index.js, into webapp folder).

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `COPY . web`. Since you renamed the folder as web.

Comment: Try `COPY web /webapp` instead.